# Hom, H$^n$ and tensor product

Tags: sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors, derived-categories, hom-functor

If $X$ is a scheme, $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf and $L$ is an ample line bundle, why it holds $H^0(X, \mathcal{F} \otimes L^n) = Hom(L^{-n}, \mathcal{F})$?

Comment: Note that it holds without any assumption other than $L$ being a line bundle : $X$ does not have to be a scheme, $\mathcal{F}$ does not have to be quasi-coherent and $L$ does not have to be ample. The thing is $H^0(X,\mathcal{F})=Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})$ and $L$ being invertible we have $$H^0(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes L^n)=Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F}\otimes L^n)=Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X\otimes L^{-n},\mathcal{F})=Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(L^{-n},\mathcal{F})$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Only a question: why does the second equality hold? Is there a book where I can find this property?

Comment: $L$ being invertible, $\otimes L^{-n}$ is an equivalence of categories, so $Hom(F,G)=Hom(F\otimes L^{-n}, G\otimes L^{-n})$.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!